# Having width and centering issues with my Dropdown Navigation Menu

Tags: html, css

So i'm having problems with the dropdown width of the hovering effect, making it fit and center under the menu button. It is basicly too much on the right of the page.

I've tried multiple things to make it work but it seems i'm to unintelligent so i'm turning to this community looking for help. If you notice any other issues with the code please tell me, id appreciate it alot.

PS: Was hard to explain my issue but if you are experienced with code and look into mine you'll probably understand what my issue is.

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'drugsregular';
    src: url('font1/drugs-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font1/drugs-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font1/drugs-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('font1/drugs-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font1/drugs-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font1/drugs-webfont.svg#drugsregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'birds_of_paradiseregular';
    src: url('font2/birds_of_paradise__personal_use_only.eot');
    src: url('font2/birds_of_paradise__personal_use_only.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font2/birds_of_paradise__personal_use_only.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('font2/birds_of_paradise__personal_use_only.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font2/birds_of_paradise__personal_use_only.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font2/birds_of_paradise__personal_use_only.svg#birds_of_paradiseregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
p {
    font-family: 'drugsregular';
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #E6E6E6;
}
p2 {
    font-family: 'drugsregular';
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'birds_of_paradiseregular';
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'drugsregular';
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 19px;
    height: 32px;
}
h3 {
    font-family: 'birds_of_paradiseregular';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
h4 {
    font-family: 'birds_of_paradiseregular';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
.Header {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #686868;
}
.Menu {
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 1024px;
    float:right;
    font-family: 'birds_of_paradiseregular';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.Menu ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
}
.Menu li {
    margin:0 auto;
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.Menu li:hover > ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 90px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'drugsregular';
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.Menu a {
    padding: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
}
.Menu a:hover {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
.Logo {
    float:left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.container1 {
    height: 400px;
}
.title {
    width: 665px;
    padding-top: 170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bkimage1 {
    background-image:url('images/bkimage1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 720px;
}
.lasmer {
    background-color: #424242;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.lasmer :hover {
    background-color: #ec4e8c;
    height: 32px;
}
.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
.firsti {

}
.firstp {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 520px;
    height: 380px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container2 {
    height: 720px;
}
.bkimage2 {
    height: 720px;
    background-image: url(images/bkimage2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Name - Start</title>

</head>
<body>
        <div class="Header">

            <div class="Logo">
                <img src="images/royalq2.png">
            </div>
            
            <div class="Menu">
                <nav>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Web Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container1">
            
            <div class="bkimage1">
                
            <div class="title">
                
                <h1>
                Royal Q
                </h1>
                <p>
                Royal Q lovar dig en parfym som du aldrig kommer glömma.
                Med unika aromer av Italiensk ursprung ger dig den en sensuell doft som är oemotståndlig...
                </p>
            
            <div class="lasmer">
                
            <a href="#content">
                
                <h2>Läs mer</h2>
            
            </a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content">
            <a name="content"></a>
                
                <div class="firstp">
                    
                <h3>Hej!</h3>
                <p2>
                Royal Q lovar dig en parfym som du aldrig kommer glömma.
                Med unika aromer av Italiensk ursprung ger dig den en sensuell doft som är oemotståndlig.
                Med detta tillkommer även en snyggt designad flaska som är ensam i sitt slag med en högklassig förpackning.
                Utöver vår parfym erbjuder vi botemedlet mot vintern.
                På royal Q erbjuder vi exotiska badbomber med olika lukter och färger.
                Dessa badbomber kommer ge dig en stund för ro och avkoppling som får dig att glömma vintertiden med ett dopp.
                </p2>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="container2">
            <div class="bkimage2">
            </div>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the dropdown menu you are using default styling for `ul` and `li` tags which adds extra padding to your elements. You need to ovewrite these.

Do the following:

```
.Menu li:hover > ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-left: 0; /* overwrite default left padding of ul tag */
    display: block;
    width: 90px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'drugsregular';
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.Menu ul li {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Further more, not sure why your `.Menu` div is so wide. This forces it to flow on the next line when using a smaller viewport. (`width: 1024px;`  is commented out in the example).

See working [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMPYEV).